# Watch a function and all its variables to use it in ngIf

Tags: angularjs, typescript, angularjs-ng-if

I want to apply a `ngIf` directive to a DOM element, this `ngIf` watch a function and that function check the values of other variables. As the following:

```
    export class Controller{

    private x: ObjectClass;

        public isDone():boolean{
         return this.x.isY() && this.otherFunction();
        }

        private otherFunction():boolean{
        let result:boolean = true;
        this.array.forEach((value)=>{
        if(!value){
        result = false;}
        });
        return result
        }
    }

//define the state 

  .state('app.first-state', {
        url: '/first-state,
        views: {
          'renderView': {
            template: require('./states/first-state.html'),
            controller: 'Controller as Ctrl',
          }
        }
      })

//in the first-state.html

    <div ng-if="Ctrl.isDone()"></div>
```

`x` is an object who is carrying methods and variables.

The `x.isY()` and `this.otherFunction()` change its return values to `true` but the ngIf does not recreate the DOM element. It seems that the digest cycle doesn't watch the `x` object neither `array` object. Which makes sense since I am not using them directly into DOM elements. However, the method `isDone()` runs only when I get into the state or I get out from the state.

I did the following workaround, but I am concerned that there will be a performance issue:

```
    private isDoneVar:boolean = false;

    //then make my "own digest cycle"
     $interval(() => {
                this.isDoneVar = this.isDone();
            }, 700);
//and in the div
        <div ng-if="Ctrl.isDoneVar"></div>
```

I have two questoins:

1. Why does the `isDone` function run when I enter and leave the state?
2. Is there any better way to tell angular to run this function each digest cycle run? Or to watch any changes for its internal variables(without adding `$watch` to each variable)

Comment: `ng-if="isDone()"` looks for an isDone function in the $scope. It doesn't seem to be on the scope.

Comment: @JBNizet I used `bindToController` but to not write a lot of code, I skipped this step. The `ngIf` calls the `isDone()` method when I enter and leave the state, so `ngIf`  "is seeing" the `isDone` function

Comment: If you want us to find a bug in your real code, post your real code. There is no wau ng-if="isDone()" calls an isDone() method of your controller. It looks for it on the scope.

Comment: @JBNizet sorry for the confusion. I have edited the question

Comment: Your code should work fine as is. isDone() probably continues returning false, even if you think it doesn't. Or you have an error somewhere: check your console. Hard to help more without a complete reproducible plunkr. Another possibility is that you update the state of the controller behind the back of Angular (for example by not using $http, but a custom ajax library).

Comment: @JBNizet What I expect is that  angular does not know anything about the internal structure of  `isDone` function, which means that angular will see that nothing is changed about the `isDone`. But  my workaround which runs the function each 700 ms and assign its value to a variable that angular is watching it, is working perfectly fine.

Comment: This assumption of yours is incorrect. Angular will call this method every time it needs to to check if its result has changed, and update the DOM accordingly. That's provided that all the changes that can potentially change its result are done via angular events: ng-xxx event handlers, $http service, $interval, etc. If you're doing something behind the back of angular, then $scope.$apply() must be called. Show the code that updates the state of the controller.

Comment: @JBNizet Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129159/discussion-between-hex-and-jb-nizet).